# change where condition based on column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I faced the following requirement. The following query is called by a procedure. The value `p_pac_code` is the input parameter of the procedure.

The requirement is the query should have an additional condition  `sp_sbsp.SUBSPCLTY_CODE!='C430` if the `p_pac_code` value is '008'.

For any other `p_pac_code` value, it should run as it is below. Is there way to do this by adding an additional condition in the WHERE clause?

As for now, I have done this using IF.....ELSE using the query two times separately depending on `p_pac_code` value. But I am required to find a way to do with just adding a condition to this single query.

```
     SELECT ptg.group_cid
     FROM PRVDR_TYPE_X_SPCLTY_SUBSPCLTY ptxss,
      PT_X_SP_SSP_STATUS pxsst ,
      pt_sp_ssp_x_group ptg,
      group_x_group_store gg,
      specialty_subspecialty sp_sbsp,
      treatment_type tt,
      provider_type pt
    WHERE 
    pt.PRVDR_TYPE_CODE          = ptxss.PRVDR_TYPE_CODE
    AND tt.TRTMNT_TYPE_CODE           = pxsst.TRTMNT_TYPE_CODE
    AND ptxss.PRVDR_TYPE_X_SPCLTY_SID = pxsst.PRVDR_TYPE_X_SPCLTY_SID
    AND tt.TRTMNT_TYPE_CODE           = p_pac_code
    AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(PXSST.FROM_DATE) AND TRUNC(PXSST.TO_DATE)
    AND ptg.prvdr_type_code        =ptxss.prvdr_type_code
    AND ptg.spclty_subspclty_sid   = ptxss.spclty_subspclty_sid
    AND ptxss.spclty_subspclty_sid = sp_sbsp.spclty_subspclty_sid
    AND ptg.spclty_subspclty_sid   = sp_sbsp.spclty_subspclty_sid
    AND ptg.status_cid             = 2
    AND ptg.group_cid              = gg.group_cid
    AND gg.group_store_cid         = 16
    AND gg.status_cid              = 2;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
AND NOT (    NVL( sp_sbsp.SUBSPCLTY_CODE, 'x' ) = 'C430'
         AND NVL( p_pac_code value,       'x' ) = '008' )
```

to the where clause.

The `NVL` function is used so that it will match `NULL` values (if they exist in your data); otherwise, even though `NULL` does not match `C430` you will still find that `NULL = 'C430'` and `NULL <> 'C430'` and `NOT( NULL = 'C430' )` will all return false.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add a condition like this:

```
... and ( 
         ( sp_sbsp.SUBSPCLTY_CODE!='C430' and p_pac_code = '008')
         OR 
         NVL(p_pac_code, '-') != '008'
        )
```

This can be re-written in different ways, this one is quite self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy. Add the following condition:

AND (sp_sbsp.SUBSPCLTY_CODE != 'C430' OR p_pac_code value != '008')

(don't forget the parenthesis)

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing

```
SELECT ptg.group_cid
FROM PRVDR_TYPE_X_SPCLTY_SUBSPCLTY ptxss
WHERE 
pt.PRVDR_TYPE_CODE = ptxss.PRVDR_TYPE_CODE 
&&((tt.TRTMNT_TYPE_CODE = pxsst.TRTMNT_TYPE_CODE) 
or (tt.TRTMNT_TYPE_CODE = pxsst.TRTMNT_TYPE_CODE))
```

just use the parenthesis to specify where the conditionmust implement.